# Регулярное выражение с исключением. Разбиение строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, typescript

Есть строка `"a:1|b:2|c:текст с \||d:3"`. Мне нужно разбить строку на части, которые разделены "|", но проигнорировать "\|", чтоб в результате было так:

`["a:1", "b:2", "c:текст с \|", "d:3"]`

Comment: Пробовали самостоятельно решить проблему? Если да, то добавьте в вопрос как пробовали сделать и какие проблемы возникли.

Comment: Что-то в таком роде, но это не работает `(?!\\\|$)(\|)\g`

Comment: `(?<!\\)\|` но я не помню, что в js с подглядыванием назад

Comment: @splash58, я тоже думал на счет предыдущего символа, но при .split(), он удаляет '\|'
`'a:1|b:2|c:3\||d:4'.split(/(?<!\\)\|/g)`
`["a:1", "b:2", "c:3", "", "d:4"]`

Comment: @splash58 в js с этим не очень хорошо, этот вариант будет работать также как и просто сделать без задников. А вариант `polRk` вообще не будет работать должным образом, останутся только `|`, за место того. чтобы оставлять только все до каждого последнего `|` за которым следует другой символ, отличный от `|`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По вопросу так:

```js
console.log("a:1|b:2|c:текст с \\||d:3".match(/(\\\||[^|])+/g))
```

Но скорее всего правильно вот так:

```js
console.log("a:1|b:2|c:текст с \\||d:3".match(/(\\.|[^|])+/g))
```

Comment: Только если в строке больше одного упоминания \| - не работает `"a:1|b:\|\|\|".match(/(\\\||[^\|])+/g)`

Comment: @polRk, когда ты пишешь строку в кавычках, ты должен экранировать обратный слеш, иначе его просто нет в строке.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я Вам о чем сказал выше?))) Блин вопрос удалили. Ладно забейте вообщем. Все равно не соответсвует задаче, зачем мне 2 слеша если требуется 1 =)  Но у вас этого прсото не получится сделать =)

Comment: @Qwertiy - А не могли бы вы объяснить данные выражения ? Как они работают ?

Comment: @And, у того ответа другой косяк. Регулярки стараются захватить самый левый из вариантов, а не самый длинный. Экранирование не при чём. `"abcde".match(/([^c]|bc)+/)[0]` будет `"ab"`, а вот `"abcde".match(/(bc|[^c])+/)[0]` - уже `"abcde"`. В том ответе та же проблема.

Comment: @polRk, см. комментарий выше.

Comment: @polRk, они отличаются тем, что во втором можно экранировать любой символ, а не только палку. Потому что если формат предполагает экранирование только палки (и не предполагает экранирование самого ```\```), то в строке будет невозможно использовать `\|`.

Comment: Мг, я тогда могу разбить строку "a:123\\:123\\:123" 
Вашим вторым выражением( с заменой палки на двоеточие)
`/(\\.|[^\:])+/g`

Comment: Я говорю не об этом, а о том, что строка может прилететь именно `c\|`, а не `c\\|`. Вот и весь расклад собстна =)

Comment: @And, не может. Строковый тип не содержит данных о том, как строка была записана в коде - она вообще может не быть литералом в коде. Тегированная строка могла бы и там это можно обработать (в ES2018), но никто не прoсил. ```function f({raw:[s]}) { return s.match(/(\\.|[^\|])+/g) }
console.log(f `a:1|b:2|c:текст с \||d:3`)```

Comment: @polRk, да, так можно. Кстати, я немного наврал в выражении, слеш в квадратных скобках означает экранирование, а оно там крайне редко нужно. Его надо либо убрать, либо удвоить. На валидных данных разницы не будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy мне ide уже сказала об этом )